# how to hash two arguments

Tags: python, sha256

Want to hash two strings the below code throws an error that SHA 256 can hash one value only.
Is there any other way to hash two arguments?

```
sign =hex(hashlib.sha256(secret,param_str))

TypeError: sha256() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: How do you defined "hashing 2 value" ? concatenating the two values and then hashing them together and get a single result ? or run the hash algorithm separately on both value and get two results totally independant ?

Comment: You could concatenate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods described in https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)

Some examples.

Method 1:

```
import hashlib, binascii
def generate_hash1(secret, param_str): 
      bsecret = secret.encode('utf-8')
      bparam_str = param_str.encode('utf-8')
      dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', bsecret, bparam_str, 100000)
      return binascii.hexlify(dk)
```

Method 2:

```
import hashlib
def generate_hash2(secret, param_str):
  dk = hashlib.sha256()
  bsecret = secret.encode('utf-8')
  bparam_str = param_str.encode('utf-8')
  dk.update(bsecret)
  dk.update(bparam_str)
  return dk.hexdigest()
```

Method 3 (equivalent to Method 2)

```
import hashlib
def generate_hash3(secret, param_str):
  dk = hashlib.sha256()
  s = secret + param_str  # concatenate strings, then hash
  dk.update(s.encode('utf-8'))
  return dk.hexdigest()
```

Results

```
print(generate_hash1("my secret", "password")) #b'8843eb1e289740e6379eed8191497788dd527164beafce1fb09e7f60adb54e1d'
print(generate_hash2("my secret", "password")) # 45bf5f14029ae0e54807be1ed048bb82d33c2100781b03007f989744961a49a9
print(generate_hash3("my secret", "password")) # 45bf5f14029ae0e54807be1ed048bb82d33c2100781b03007f989744961a49a9
```